# Остановка стороннего метода по таймеру c#

Tags: c#

Есть метод сторонней библиотеки. Он обращается к серверу и либо получает данные и завершается, либо через 10 секунд автоматически закрывается. Завершение метода быстрее чем за 10 секунд не предусмотрено. Мне же надо его закрывать по истечении 100 миллисекунд работы. Хотелось бы сделать это без многопоточности. Есть идеи как это сделать?

Comment: Асинхронное выполнение. Для отмены задачи используется токен отмены

Comment: Можете привезти пример выполнения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привожу

Намного удобнее составлять композиции асинхронных операций посредством `Task`ов. Поэтому, посмотрите, есть ли у api Вашей сторонней библиотеки поддержка `Task`ов?

Если да, то Ваш ответ в этих строчках

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(100);//отменяет задачу после указанного числа миллисекунд

        var res = TaskWrap(cts.Token);//функции с поддержками тасков обычно имеют перегрузку с CancellationToken
        Console.WriteLine(res.Result);
    }
```

Если же api сторонней библиотеки не поддерживает `Task`и, то надо обернуть колбэк ответа в `TaskCompletionSource` и продолжить работу с таском

```
    static Task<string> TaskWrap(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        ct.Register(()=> {/* остановить загрузку, чтоб данные больше приходили, если это возможно*/ tcs.SetException(new TimeoutException()); });
        YourFunctionCallback(answer => tcs.SetResult(answer));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Если исходников метода у вас нет — никак. Вы не можете остановить чужой код.

Правильная имплементация отмены задания — кооперативная: код, который вы хотите остановить, должен *сотрудничать*. Если вы прервёте его каким-то образом, то в лучшем случае вы оставите его структуры данных в неконсистентном состоянии, а в худшем — прервёте выполнение нативного кода в состоянии заблокированного heap lock'а.

Если библиотека не сотрудничает, не используйте её или потребуйте/попросите у авторов законную возможность управления отменой.

---

Вы, конечно, можете запустить сторонний метод в соседнем потоке, и по окончанию срока ожидания просто плюнуть на этот код и позволить ему дальше бежать, игнорируя результат. Это, понятно, далеко не самый лучший дизайн: вы блокируете поток надолго ради одной короткой операции.